# how to delete the first character if the first character is a zero | Android | TextWatcher

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

i have question about how to delete the first character if the first character is a zero .

ex : 
`0887` to `887`

here i'm using Text Watcher for my Edit Text. but it's not working

here is my code :

```
  @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (edtPhone.getText().charAt(start) == '0'){
            edtPhone.getText().delete(start, start);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
```

i'm so confused whats wrong in my code 
any help or suggestion will be appreciate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the first character is 0, then using the ***substring*** method extract the string except for the first character, then set it to the **EditText**.

Code in Kotlin:

```
 phone_number_edt.doOnTextChanged { text: CharSequence?, start, count, after ->
        val length = text.toString().length

        if ((text.toString()[0] == '0')) {
            if (length > 1) {
                email_edt.setText(
                    text.toString().substring(
                        1,
                        length
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (edtPhone.getText().charAt(start) == '0'){
            String textValue = edtPhone.getText().toString();
            edtPhone.setText(textValue.substring(1, textValue.length());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private fun removeZeroFromFirstPosition(editext: EditText?) {
       editext?.apply {
            addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
                override fun beforeTextChanged(s:CharSequence?,start: Int,count: Int, after: Int){}

                override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                    if (text.isNotEmpty()) {
                        if (text[0].toString() == "0") {
                            val textValue = text.toString()
                            setText(textValue.substring(1, textValue.length))
                        }
                    }
                }

                override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {}
            })
        }
    }
```